# Why my map method is returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am really focusing on this problem, I can not find any mistake in my code.
I just want the array to contain the inner text of the paragraphs which has the class of true.
Thanks in advance.

```js
function x() {
  let correct = document.querySelectorAll(
    `#circle p`
  );
  let pArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(correct);
  let pCorrectArr = pArr.map(cur => {
    if (cur.classList.contains("true")) {
      const innerText = cur.innerText;
      return innerText;
    }
  });
  return pCorrectArr;
}

console.log(x());
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <p>Google</p>
  <p class="true">Facebook</p>
  <p>Microsoft</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you didn't wrote `else`. And you should be using `filter` then `map` to get only text for nodes having class = `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map would return an array with the same number of elements as the source array. Hence in your case, when you do not enter the `if` condition, you return "nothing". Javascript assumes a function which has returned nothing to have returned `undefined`.

In your example, your if condition returns a `string`, while the other case just returns `undefined`. This is the reason you're seein `undefined` mixed with your expected strings.

You could use `reduce` instead to achieve what you want, `reduce` allows you to iterate over an array and create your own response. (you could return an array with more items, fewer items or an object that is not an array itself )

Here is your example code modified to work with `reduce` the way you want it. I'd suggest [reading up on `reduce` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function x() {
  let correct = document.querySelectorAll(
    `#circle p`
  );
  let pArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(correct);
  let pCorrectArr = pArr.reduce(function(acc, cur){
    if (cur.classList.contains("true")) {
      const innerText = cur.innerText;
      acc.push(innerText);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return pCorrectArr;
}

console.log(x());
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <p>Google</p>
  <p class="true">Facebook</p>
  <p>Microsoft</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could look into using reduce for getting custom array.

Comment: I have never used reduce before, I'm going to google for it. Thanks for help. I'll mark your question as the answer after 7 minutes.

Comment: @KyleTech, I have updated the answer to reflect working code snippet for you to test and adapt.

Comment: sorry, may I ask a question? How the accumulator knew that it's type must be an array? for example why it's not an object by default?

Answer (score 2):

You could filter and return `innerText` by mapping this property.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns another value for every item, but does not filter an array.

For this case, take [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and add a mapping for the wanted property.

```js
function x() {
    let correct = document.querySelectorAll('#circle p'); // no need for template strings
    return Array.prototype.slice
        .call(correct)
        .filter(cur => cur.classList.contains("true"))    // filter
        .map(({ innerText }) => innerText);               // map
}

console.log(x());
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <p>Google</p>
  <p class="true">Facebook</p>
  <p>Microsoft</p>
</div>
```